# Emails with specific links in its body won't delivered

Tags: php, wordpress, email, html-email, webmail

I have a wordpress website, I sent a newsletters email to 88 subscriber one time, all the 88 emails delivered well. After that immediately I was unable to send any email contains cgees.com link in the email body.
If I send any email with any links inside without mentioning cgees.com/...., all emails reach their destination, but when including cgees.com/... they just don't reach although it say " sent ".

I checked the spam folders and no emails there, tried to send to lot of domains ( yahoo, hotmail, gmail, and other domains ) and no email delivered at all, I also tried to send email directly from website, outlook and webmail and all of them say " sent " but no emails delivered.

I tried to send an email contains cgees.com from my personal hotmail email and the email delivered normally. its only happening when I try to send from my domain email addresses.

Can any body give me a hope solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like *MXTool.com* to check about your domain to see if it has any issues. As for emails not reaching there is a paid service like *ReturnPath* that can let you know what went wrong where.

Hope that the help you needed.

Cheers

Comment: I have solved the problem, it was blocked from my hosting company with no reasons.
Thank you for your reply :)